# How to use DNF to find out package versions available in a different release of Fedora?

Tags: fedora, repository, dnf

Is it possible to use `dnf` (or another utility) to search repositories of different releases of Fedora?

For instance to search my current release for all versions of a package I can do `dnf --showduplicates list <package name>`. Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

`dnf --showduplicates list [--fedora29] <package name>`

Where the argument `[--fedora29]` can be used to specify the version of Fedora that I would like to search?

If this is not possible to do using `dnf` is there a different command line tool that I can use?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can pass dnf a `--releasever=` argument to override the version.

For the particular command you gave as an example, use the following:

```
 dnf --releasever=29 --showduplicates list $pkgname
```

Comment: Here is a reminder of [Fedora releases](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/) to use alongside this command.

Comment: @Metafaniel Here's a newer URL https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora-secondary/releases/ (the current latest stable version is 38).